# Opening an EPS file in Inkscape causes weird line artifacts

Tags: svg, vector-graphics, inkscape, eps

I'm trying to edit a vector graphics file from Freepik. The format is EPS and after installing both Inkscape and Ghostscript on Windows, I'm able to open the file with Inkscape. However, Inkscape introduces some weird artifacts (see lines and wrong colors in the picture below).
[Side by side comparison, original vector (left) and SVG saved after opening the EPS file in Inkscape (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbvAW.png)
Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Be aware that you may well get voted down because non-programming questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

However, are you are able to cut down your EPS file to just a few of the objects that are rendering badly, and post the small EPS and the resultant Inkscape file? We will be able to give you better advice if we can actually see and investigate the problem with the original vector files.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little difficult to tell, partly because this is a complex illustration and partly because the rendering is a little small. I'd suggest that the circular artefacts are caused by radial fills not being rendered completely.

This could simply be a rendering problem with Inkscape, or it could be that the radial fill has an Extend parameter which isn't being honoured. It could also be a problem calculating a clip.

It's not entirely obvious what you used to render the left hand image, is that Ghostscript ?

Generally I'd say this looks like an Inkscape bug and you should report it as such.

### Edit

Reading through the Inkscape FAQ it seems that Inkscape uses SVG as its native format. That's going to mean that an awful lot of PostScript (and PDF) vector objects aren't going to be represented well. Shadings will either have to be rendered to an image or converted into a complex series of SVG primitives.

Following the link on 'How to open EPS files in Windows' from the FAQ suggests to me that EPS files are either rendered to an image or converted to PDF.

You could use Ghostscript to convert the EPS to PDF yourself, and then try loading the PDF into Inkscape to see if you get a better result. You can also open the PDF in, say, Acrobat to see if it looks OK there.

If the PDF looks fine in Acrobat, but not so good in Inkscape, then I'd say that's an Inkscape problem. If the PDF looks poor in Acrobat then that's a Ghostscript problem.

You can then report the problem as a bug to the appropriate site.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, KenS. It seems the problem is with highlights not being properly supported by the SVG format. The "lines" in the image are weird because they remain 1 pixel wide when I zoom in in Inkscape. I haven't found a way to get rid of them.

Comment: I think Inkscape opens EPS files by first converting them to PDF with GhostScript. I'll take a look at the PDF and report back.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that EPS has more capabilities than SVG and that's why some stuff looks weird when converted to PDF/SVG. Specifically, highlights in an EPS file are not properly rendered in an SVG file.
I checked the conversion from EPS to PDF via Ghostscript and the lines are already there, i.e. it's not an Inkscape bug.
Here's the original file to reproduce the problem:
https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/data-processing-factory-isometric-technology_8625296.htm
And here's what it looks like after converting it to PDF: [The artifacts are not as noticeable on the PDF file, possibly because Ghostscript converts it with a higher DPI by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7iF6.png)

My workaround to be able to edit the file (remove the background) was to:

- open the EPS with Inkscape, ungroup the items
- delete the background
- export it as PNG
- then use the PNG as a "mask" on GIMP to edit the JPG file that came together with the EPS.

Comment: Its good to know you have a workaround. In fact I believe the problem may actually be rendering. When I create a PDF file using Ghostscript and open it in Acrobat, I see the artefacts, when I render it with Ghostscript I do not. So I altered the Acrobat settings to turn off 'smooth text', 'smooth line art', 'smooth images' etc. The culprit seems to be 'smooth line art', if I turn that off then (in Acrobat) the problem disappears. I believe that is Acrobat anti-aliasing the lines and what you are seeing is the 'blurred' edge of the original line shining through.

Comment: Which command line options did you use to disable "smooth line art"?

Comment: In Acrobat ? No command line options, its under (on Windows, Acrobat X) Edit->Preferences then select PageDisplay from the list on the left. On the right in the 'Rendering' group of controls, if you have 'Use 2D graphics acceleration turned on, uncheck it, that should then allow you to alter 'Smooth line art'. With that checked I see your problem in the PDF file, with it off, I do not. My suspicion is that there are two objects overlying each other. The top one is clipped (can't anti-alias clip) so edge is sharp. The obscured object underneath, however is not clipped and you see the 'blur'